# In IntelliJ, is there a way to modify the decompiled class in the bytecode viewer?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bytecode, decompiling

By default, the bytecode viewer is in read-only mode.

Is there a way to modify the code and save to a new class file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a plug-in called [Bytecode Editor](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8461-bytecode-editor):

> Provides View | Edit Bytecode action for those who learns JVM
>   internals.
>
> Based on ByteCode Viewer by JetBrains but is better:
>
> - it uses an editor tab instead of a popup
> - it **allows you to edit bytecode assembler and assemble edited code back into .class files**
> - it provides default hotkey for bytecode analysis: Ctrl+K, Ctrl+B

Comment: How can you save edited code back into .class file?

Comment: @Andrei the best place to ask would be https://github.com/pshirshov/idea-bytecode-editor/issues.

Comment: Thanks, @CrazyCoder !

Comment: That plugin is outdated and no longer works unfortunately. Any alternatives?